# When can you count ladies towards a Minyan?

Tags: halacha, women, minyan

I've heard that there are situations in which one can count the ladies towards a [Minyan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minyan). Is that true? Which situations?

Comment: See here for a comprehensive discussion of the issue:
http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/english/tfila/frimer2-1.htm

Answer (score 13):

I think it's the case where a non-Jew  is trying to force a Jew to violate any mitzvah (or even any established Jewish custom) out of opposition to Judaism (rather than for some personal benefit). If ten Jews - and if I recall correctly, women are included - know about the situation, then as part of the mitzvah of kiddush Hashem, the Jew has to allow himself or herself to be killed rather than violate the mitzvah.

(Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh De'ah 157:1. Pischei Teshuvah there :7 mentions the question whether women count towards the ten, and references his comments to Yoreh De'ah 2:6, but I haven't yet found it there.)

Comment: I didn't get that the Pischei Teshuva since kiddush Hashem b'rabim is learned from the same pasuk as saying, for example, kadish with a minyan.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be his question - whether בני ישראל comes to exclude women or geirim. It's too bad that I don't know the other place he's referring to, so I could see what arguments he brings to bear.

Answer (score 10):

When you light Chanuka candles in Shul there is supposed to be a Minyan there. The Shaalos U'Teshuvos Rav Paalim in Orach Chaim Chelek 2 Siman 62 says that you can count ladies towards this Minyan.

Answer (score 10):

One should try to read the Megillah for at least 10. [There is a disagreement about whether women may be counted towards this total.](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14327&st=&pgnum=436)