# Where does R' Ovadia Yosef write that women can contribute towards a Minyan for lighting the Menorah?

Tags: sources-mekorot, chanuka, menora-chanukia, hacham-ovadia-yosef

I know there is [another question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4323/when-can-you-count-ladies-towards-a-minyan) that discusses others sources:
I am specifically looking for the source in יביע אומר quoted in [ילקוט יוסף תרעא:טו](http://kodeshblog.com/tora/f_01355_all.html?dyn)

> בית כנסת שעדיין לא הגיעו המתפללים להתפלל מנחה בערב שבת, ויש שם רוב מנין, וגם כמה נשים הנמצאות בעזרת נשים שבבית הכנסת, אפשר לצרף את הנשים למנין עשרה להדלקת נרות חנוכה שבבית הכנסת, ובפרט כשיבואו אחר כך עוד אנשים ויהיה מנין בבית הכנסת.
>
> [לפי מ"ש הר"ן (מגילה יט:) שכיון שהנשים חייבות במקרא מגילה ומוציאות את האנשים, ודאי שמצטרפות עם האנשים למנין... וראה עוד בשו"ת יביע אומר ח"י בהערות לרב פעלים ח"ב סימן סב].

Comment: How do you know it's in Yabia Omer at all?

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1401&pgnum=300

Comment: @DoubleAA Read the bottom line where he quotes Yabia Omer Vol 10.

Comment: @GershonGold Thanks - the Ben Ish Chai isn't convinced. I'd seen that, though want to see what R' Ovadia wrote on this.

Answer (score 4):

At the back of Yabia Omer Vol 10 OC (Siman 55), he has notes on Rav Poalim. There, in section 37 he writes as follows:

> ח"ב חאו"ח סימן סב.
>
> נשאל הרהמ"ח על מ"ש הרמ"א (סי' תרו ס"א) שאם ביקש מחילה מחבירו כדת, ולא רצה למחול לו, יאמר אח"כ בפני עשרה שביקש ממנו מחילה.
>
> האם מועיל לומר כן אפילו בפני עשר נשים.
>
> והשיב, דלכתחלה יאמר במעמד עדה שהם אנשים, ובדיעבד אם אמר כן בפני עשר נשים, יצא, וא"צ להטריחו שיאמר בפני עשרה גברים.
>
> ואגב העיר הרהמ"ח שיש להסתפק כיו"ב במאי דקי"ל (בש"ע סי' תרעא ס"ז), שמדליקים נרות חנוכה בבית הכנסת בברכות, משום פרסומי ניסא.
>
> ובשערי תשובה הביא בשם הגאון יעב"ץ שצריך שיהיו עשרה בשעת ההדלקה שאז יש פרסומי ניסא, שיוכל לברך ג"כ.
>
> ויש להסתפק אם נמצאו שם עשר נשים אם יוכל להדליק בברכה.
>
> וכתב לפשוט דין זה ממ"ש הרמ"א (סי' תרצ), בהא דקי"ל מגילה בי"ד ובט"ו צריך לכתחלה לחזר אחר עשרה, שיש להסתפק אם נשים מצטרפות לעשרה.
>
> וכתב הפרי חדש שכל דאיכא היכר צירופן אינן מצטרפות משום פריצותא.
>
> והרי התם מה שצריך עשרה הוא לפרסומי ניסא, ועם כל זה כל שאין הדבר ניכר שעושים משום צירוף, י"ל דמהני צירוף נשים לעשרה לפרסום הנס, ואפשר לברך על ההדלקה.
>
> וה"ה שיש לפשוט בזה ספק הפתחי תשובה ביו"ד (סי' ב סק"ב) גבי מחלל שבת "בפרהסיא" שפסול לשחיטה, אם חילל בפני עשר נשים, מהו, ולפי האמור חשיב פרהסיא גם בפני נשים. עכת"ד.
>
> והנה בשו"ת אור גדול (סי' א דף ב ע"ג) הביא מה שנסתפק הדבר שמואל אבוהב (סי' סג) הובא בגליון מהרש"א (יו"ד סי' קנז), לענין קידוש ה' בפרהסיא, אם נשים נחשבות ממנין פרהסיא, והשיב האור גדול, שכיון שגם הן מצוות על קידוש השם, פשיטא שגם הן מצטרפות לעשרה.  ע"ש.
>
> וכן העלה בשו"ת מהר"י אשכנזי (חיו"ד סי' טז) בד"ה וכאשר, בדין מחלל שבת בפרהסיא, שמכיון דהא דבעינן עשרה, הוא משום דהוי חוצפא יתרה, שכופר בפרהסיא במעשה בראשית, אין חילוק בין עשרה אנשים לעשר נשים.  ע"ש.
>
> וע"ע בשו"ת פני מבין (חיו"ד סי' קב, ובמפתחות דף קיט סע"א), ובשו"ת עמודי אש (דף נב סע"א), מ"ש בזה.
>
> ויש להעיר ממ"ש הגר"ח אלפסי בספר משחא דרבותא (א"ח סי' תרצ, דף ריא ע"ב), יש להסתפק אם עשר נשים שומעות מקרא מגילה, אם יש לברך להן ברכת האל הרב את ריבנו, שאינה נאמרת אלא בעשרה, כמ"ש הרמ"א (סי' תרצב).
>
> ולכאורה הדעת נוטה שיש לברך להן.  ע"כ.
>
> וזה על סמך מאי דקי"ל (מגילה ד א) נשים חייבות במקרא מגילה שאף הן היו באותו הנס.
>
> וגם לגבי נשים שייך פרסומי ניסא, כאשר העלה הרהמ"ח.
>
> ויש להוסיף עוד על פי האמור במאי דקי"ל בהרמב"ם (סוף פ"ב מהל' תשובה), ומרן בש"ע (סי' תרו ס"ב), אם מת אשר חטא לו מביא עשרה בני אדם ומעמידם על קברו, ואומר חטאתי לאלקי ישראל ולפלוני זה שחטאתי לו.
>
> (והם ישיבו לו "מחול לך" ג' פעמים ), שהוא הדין שגם נשים מצטרפות לכך.  ודו"ק.