# Why are public sacrifices always male but personal ones are not?

Tags: korban, maseches-temura

In [T'murah 2:1](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22431&pgnum=264), the Mishna says:

> קרבנות היחיד נוהגין בזכרים ובנקבות, וקרבנות הציבור אינן נוהגין אלא בזכרים.
>   Personal sacrifices can be male or female, but public sacrifices are always male.
>   <sub>(my own translation)</sub>

I looked through Kehati, and he does not provide any explanation of the reasoning behind this distinction.

Is this discussed anywhere else, perhaps somewhere where the topic is less tangentially related?

What is the reason for this distinction? **Why are personal sacrifices either male or female while public ones are always male?**

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/80379/does-judaism-consider-women-inferior#comment253198_80402

Comment: BTW it is not literally 'always' https://www.sefaria.org/Temurah.14a.12